# How do I make a generic factory in javascript?

Tags: javascript

A factory class isn't the end product I am looking for but it is basically my problem boiled down.  I am looking for a class we'll call foo that can be passed in another class bar as a parameter to its constructor such that when later calling fooInstance.create() it returns a new instance of bar.  I can easily figure out how to make a fooInstance.create(bar) create an instance of bar.  But that isn't what I need.  I need each instance of the factory class to create a specific type of object.  so:

```
    fooCar = new foo(Car);
    fooTruck = new foo(Truck);
    myCar = fooCar.create();
    myTruck = fooTruck.create();
```

This would be something easily handled by Generics in c#.  I either get errors or I end up screwing with the prototype of foo which then changes the type created by all instances of foo.

Comment: What extra things is your `foo` class supposed to do. Javascript won't give you the static type safety you are looking for so perhaps you could instead opt for something simpler, such as assigning `fooCar = Car` and ignoring the create method completely: `myCar = new fooCar`.

Comment: Check this out http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a regular object from your factory, with just one `create` method:

```js
function foo (Constructor) {
    return {
        create: function () {
            return new Constructor();
        }
    };
}
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fR5Gz/1/

Comment: Thanks!! That was so deceptively short and simple that I thought it was a plain factory at first.

Comment: @user1989150 - It *is* a plain factory. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your help. @missingno I thought the details of what I was trying to do would cloud the issue but now I think it was the other way around. I'll know better for next time. I wasn't looking for type safety but without it maybe there is no reason to do it this way. Maybe I'm stuck in classical thinking.

I actually figured it out myself this morning because I didn't get any email alerts on this thread like I was supposed to so I thought there weren't any replies yet. This is my solution (relevant code only):

```
    ORM.Repository = (function (){
    function Repository(ob){
        this.construct = ob;
    };
    //bunch of other generic repository stuff deleted
    Repository.prototype.make = function () { return new this.construct();}
    return Repository;
})();
```

Usage:

```
    var carRepository = new ORM.Repository(car);
    var personRepository = new ORM.Repository(person);
    var myCar = carRepository.make();
    var user = personRepository.make();
```

Comment: Have you looked at Resourceful? It's part of the Flatiron project and provides a mechanism for generating ORM models. https://github.com/flatiron/resourceful